# NSRange output of location and length

Tags: objective-c, nslog, nsrange

An issue I have (maybe it is really easy to solve, but I am new to Obj-C.
I want to print out the location and length of NSRange I created, but I get an error message. Here the code

```
NSRange tmpRange = [newData rangeOfData:segmentToFind options:kNilOptions range:NSMakeRange(0u, [newData length])];

NSLog(@"%@ - range location : %lu", [tmpRange location];
```

The error message I get is:

```
Bad receiver type 'NSRange' (aka 'struct _NSRange')
```

Comment: You have 2 placeholders, and only one argument in the `NSLog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSRange starts with the letters NS, but it isn't an NSObject. It is an ordinary struct, like a struct in C or in C++. So to access location and length, you just use range.location and range.length. There are other structs like that, like NSRect, NSPoint, NSSize.

You noticed already what the compiler said: NSRange is a typedef for the type "struct _NSRange { ... }".

And then there are types like NSInteger and NSUInteger which also start with NS but which are really just primitive types (int or long, unsigned int or unsigned long).

Answer (score 4):

To solutions:

A. You have to log each component separately:

```
NSLog( @"%lu - %lu", (long)range.location, (long)range.length );
```

B. You can convert it to an instance of `NSString` and then log the string:

```
NSLog( @"%@", NSStringFromRange(range) );
```

Output

```
{1, 2}
```

`NSStringFrom…()` is similar to `-description` and exists for many types including `NSSize`, `NSPoint`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the NSStringFrom... functions.